# How do I turn off or repurpose the CAPSLOCK key?

Tags: keyboard, capslock

**Update: My main goal is to change the function (or even turn off) the CAPSLOCK key.**

At work, we have a long domain name. I'm lazy. I'd like to map my CAPSLOCK key to type out a string such as "outlongdomain.com". This is only to save me from typing.

I've seen [numerous](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23491) [questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50210) about how to remap the key to a different function. While neat; I couldn't see how to tell the system to "print out these next set of letters where the cursor has focus."

**Update:**
I would like to use Autokey but I don't see an option for CAPSLOCK
[image]

Comment: See the section on autokey in http://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard

Comment: Great Utility but I don't see an option for CAPSLOCK

Comment: Why not create a .desktop file that will open firefox or other browser of your choice on that domain ? Or create a separate shortcut on another key ? Want me to post that as answer ?

Comment: @Serg I've never created a desktop file. Yes, I'm looking for a working solution in gnome shell.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that capslock is a hardware key, and can't be reassigned, kind of like the fn key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can be satisfied with it just being disabled, here's what you can do.

1. Run `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`.
2. Open Tweak Tool by searching for it in the Dash.
3. Select the Typing menu and change Caps lock key behavior to `Disabled`.

[image: Example]

Source: https://mkaz.com/2014/02/08/disable-caps-lock-in-ubuntu/

Comment: works even in Ubuntu 16.10!

Comment: this solution is easy but incomplete, this will only work under gnome applications, and won't work, for example, in wine applications

Answer (score 2):

To remap the Capslock to something like <kbd>Control</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, I'd recommend using the [`gnome-tweak-tool`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-tweak-tool/).

Open the `Tweak Tool` application or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> and run `gnome-tweak-tool`.

Select the "Typing" tab, and change the dropdown for `Caps Lock key Behaviour`.

Here's how it looks on my system:

[image: The Gnome Tweak Tool on the 'Typing' Tab.]

Now for making a key combination to type "outlongdomain.com":

I have scoured the internet for an answer to this question, but I haven't found anything straightforward, so here's my workaround idea using the [`xclip`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/xclip.1.html) package:

Open `Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts` and add a shortcut. Name it whatever you want, and use this command:

```
echo "hello" | xclip -selection clipboard
```

But replacing "hello" with your long domain name that you want to type. Now just click the `Disabled` text on the shortcut and set it to whatever you set your <kbd>Capslock</kbd> key to.

Now when you use the new keyboard shortcut, that long domain name will instantly be copied to your clipboard, ready to use with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>

Comment: I have been using xmodmap since early X-windows days, and this still works flawlessly. Run `man xmodmap` and you should get some good examples.   For console (i.e. `/dev/tty*`), you can use dumpkeys and loadkeys combo to manipulate key-mapping. However, if you are using GNOME, `gnome-tweak-tool` is the most simple solution and will save you lots of hassle.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution #1**:

Create a new shortcut in System Settings -> keyboard -> shortcuts tab -> custom shortcuts, click <kbd>+</kbd> in the lower left, and name it whatever you like. For command type `firefox yoururl.com.
[image]

Next , assign the buttons by clicking on the right side once, and pressing the buttons you want

[image]

**Solution #2**

Make sure you enable "Run executable files" in file manager preferences, create a text file on your Desktop with the following contents

```
#!/bin/sh
firefox yourlongurl.com
```

Now, in terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>), make that file executable by running `sudo chmod +x Desktop/yourfilename`.

Now you can double click on that file as if it were a shortcut.

**Solution #3**

With <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>HOME</kbd> buttons you can access homepage in firefox so you can also set your long URL as bookmark or home-page in firefox or whatever browser you use.

Comment: Good but I specifically want to map the CAPS LOCK key and replace it's functionality.

Answer (score 1):

- Check keycode of <kbd>Caps</kbd> key:

  1. Run:

     ```
     xev -event keyboard
     ```
  2. Press/Release <kbd>Caps</kbd> key.
- To disable `Caps_Lock`

  1. Create `~/.xmodmap` file contains

     ```
     remove Lock = Caps_Lock
     keycode 66 =
     ```
  2. Add this line to `~/.xinitrc` to be run on startup

     ```
     xmodmap .xmodmap
     ```

  If you want test run `xmodmap .xmodmap` in the terminal.
- Assign long string to its key

  1. Install `xbindkeys` & `xautomation`
  2. Create `~/.xbindkeysrc` file contains

     ```
     "xte 'str outlongdomain.com'"
       Release + c:66
     ```
  3. Add this line to `~/.xinitrc` to be run on startup

     ```
     xbindkeys
     ```

  As above, to test run it in terminal.

**References:**

- [Disabling caps lock by setxkbmap makes it Shift key in Emacs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26946/disabling-caps-lock-by-setxkbmap-makes-it-shift-key-in-emacs/26947#26947)
- [How can I change what keys on my keyboard do? (How can I create custom keyboard commands/shortcuts?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated?

Just use an ALIAS for this. And for everything else that get's on your nerves, too.

It's easy to do, auto-loaded with the bash and you can even choose your own name for it. It so much fun and so easy to make.

You just need a file, and your command

Go into your home folder and create the file put an ALIAS into it. As an example

```
echo "ALIAS hp='wget http://thisisareallongnameforanurl.com'" > /home/${USER}/.bash_aliases
```

then to directly use it, do

```
source .bash_aliases
```

I called the ALIAS hp. So you just type hp into a terminal and your command will be executed.

This works with any command or script.

To autoload the aliases when you open a terminal, make sure that the following section in your .bashrc file is not commented out.

```
# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

but AFAIR correctly it's on by default.

To add more just

```
echo "ALIAS hp2='wget http://thisurlisevenmuchlongerthenthefirsone.com'" >> /home/${USER}/.bash_aliases
```

Comment: My main goal is to remap my CAPS LOCK key. At this point I'd be happy to remap it to TAB.

Comment: another way would be to bet on a logitech g15 gaming keyboard. these are older but supported. you have 18 programmable keys and a small display you could use. [check it](http://wiki.spectralcoding.com/_media/info:logitech_g15.jpg)